# How to handle route param updates nuxt.js

Tags: vue-router, nuxt.js

If the destination is the same as the current route and only params are changing (eg: going from one profile to another /users/1 -> /users/2) How can I recognize this and update the component. With vue-router I can just use the beforeRouteUpdate method to update the component.

[Here is a recording of my issue](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y3dfalqr5s0xg9f/nuxt_routing_broken.mov?dl=0)

Comment: have you tried using global guard beforeEach?

Comment: Awesome, that worked. For some reason that didn't work when I tried earlier. Once I restarted webpack it worked. Thank you

Comment: \m/(~.^) good to hear it

Answer (score 0):

I created an routeGaurds.js file inside the middleware directory and then added that middleware inside my nuxt.config.js file

// routeGaurds.js

```
export default ({ app }) => {
    if(process.browser) {

        app.router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
            console.log(to)
            next()
        })
    }
```

// nuxt.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
      router: {
        linkActiveClass: 'active-link',
        middleware: ['routeGaurds']
    }}
```